# Order of the group is between $30$ and $54$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If the order of a group is between $30$ and $54$ and we know some elements $a,b,c$ or order $2,3,7$ respectively, can I then determine every of the group in terms of given $3$ elements:

I guess the order is $42$ (should divide $2,3,7$). How can I prove or disprove whether for any divisor of $42$ there is an element of that order, Sylow theorems or so ?

Comment: What does "determine" mean? The three elements will generate the group, so every element will be a product of these three (multiple times in some order, no assumption of commutativity).

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks. Then the group is $\mathbb Z_{42}$, no other possibilites ?

Comment: There are $6$ isomorphism classses of groups of order $42$.

Comment: @Derek Holt If the group is abelian (I forgot to mention), then by the structure theorem only one survives ?

Comment: Yes that's right, all abelian groups of order $42$ are cyclic.